# Accessing list index from imported XML file

Tags: python

I've imported an XML file into my script and storing the information in an arry but I'm unsure how to access the index's because they're being stored as "Element 'value' at 0x000002937FCB4638".

Here the code that gets me to that point.

```
doc = xml.parse(path)
root = doc.getroot()
for student in root:
    students[student] = {}

    for value in student:
        students[student][value] = value.text
```

The XML file itself is simple:

```
<students>
<studentname>
<data>value</data>
</studentname>
</students>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
for student in root:
        students[student.tag] = {}

        for value in student:
            students[student.tag][value.tag] = value.text
```